# how to get a specific point's coordinate on a web page without xpath or id location using python selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to locate a point from a web page, it's a input box, I tried to use it's id to locate, but it's not accurate, I still cannot find the position of the specific point in that input box, can you please help me to figure it out? Many THX!

here is the code that I tried:

```
driver.find_element("id", xxx).location['x']
```